# Django tests work using SQLite but not MySQL

Tags: django, unit-testing

The tests that I have written for my Django application have been working perfectly during initial development where I have been using SQLite.  Now that I am getting ready to deploy I have setup a MySQL server (as that is what I'll be deploying to) but now some of my tests are failing.

Lastly the tests that are failing don't fail when I manually test the functionality.

What could be going on?

I'm not doing anything unusual, all of the views do some database shenanigans and return a response.  There isn't anything timing related (no threading or anything).

The tests all inherit from django.test.TestCase and I'm not using any fixtures.

Here is an example of a test that fails.

```
class BaseTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        super(BaseTest, self).setUp()

        self.userCreds = dict(username='test', password='a')

        # Create an admin user
        admin = models.User.objects.create_superuser(
            email='', username='admin', password='a')

        # Create a user and grant them a licence
        user = models.User.objects.create_user(
            email='some@address.com', first_name="Mister",
            last_name="Testy", **self.userCreds)

        profile = models.getProfileFor(user)
        node = profile.createNode(
            '12345', 'acomputer', 'auser',
            'user@email.com', '0456 987 123')

        self.node = node

class TestClientUIViews(BaseTest):
    def test_toggleActive(self):
        url = reverse('toggleActive') + '?nodeId=%s' % self.node.nodeId

        self.assertFalse(self.node.active)

        # This should fail because only authenticated users can toggle a node active
        resp = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 403)
        self.assertFalse(self.node.active)

        # Login and make sure visiting the url toggles the active state
        self.client.login(**self.userCreds)
        resp = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTrue(self.node.active)

        resp = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)
        self.assertFalse(self.node.active)
```

And here is what the model looks like:

```
class Node(models.Model):
    @property
    def active(self):
        '''
        Activation state gets explictly tracked in its own table but is
        exposed as a property for the sake of convenience
        '''
        activations = NodeActivation.objects \
            .filter(node=self) \
            .order_by('-datetime')

        try:
            return activations[0].active
        except IndexError:
            return False

    @active.setter
    def active(self, state):
        if self.active != state:
            NodeActivation.objects.create(node=self, active=state)

class NodeActivation(models.Model):
    node = models.ForeignKey("Node")
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetimeM.datetime.now)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

My local MySQL is 5.5.19 (so its using InnoDB) but I get the same failures on the deployment server which is using 5.1.56.  The tests fail regardless of the storage engine.

And as I mentioned at the beginning, if I switch back to use a SQLite database, all the tests go back to passing.

Comment: From what test base class do your tests derive? eg `TestCase`.  Please update your question with a simple example of a test that is failing, complete with class structure.

Comment: What's the error message when the test is failing? Do you use some fixtures in your test or some factories?

Comment: @AustinPhillips - I've added the code from one of the failing tests.  It fails right at the end, the last assertion (commented)

Comment: @François - the error message is just "AssertionError: True is not False".  I'm not using fixtures or factories.  I have overridden the setUp method to populate the db with some very basic initial data however.

Comment: @Hamish What is `self.node`?  If it correct that you expect the last line of your test to `assertFalse` when the same test above should `assertTrue`?

Comment: @AustinPhillips self.node is data that gets created by the setUp method.  The self.client.get(url) is testing a url that toggles the active state of the node.  So yes to your question.  :)

Comment: If `self.node` is a Model instance, doesn't it need to be reloaded from the db between asserts?

Comment: @AustinPhillips yes it looks like that's the issue here. It's weird this test was working at all in the first place.

Comment: @AustinPhillips the "active" member is actually a property which retrieves a node activation record and returns the value on that record.  Let me see if I can add some more code to the post to make it clearer...  In short, what you're suggesting isn't the problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By changing the active property on the Node model class to this:

```
@property
def active(self):
    '''
    Activation state gets explictly tracked in its own table but is
    exposed as a property for the sake of convenience
    '''
    activations = NodeActivation.objects \
        .filter(node=self) \
        .order_by('-id')

    try:
        return activations[0].active
    except IndexError:
        return False
```

the problem goes away.

Note the change to the `order_by` call.

The records were getting created so quickly that ordering by datetime wasn't deterministic, hence the erratic behaviour.  And I guess SQLite is just slower than MySQL which is why it wasn't a problem when using it as the backing database.

NOTE: Thanks to [Austin Phillips](https://stackoverflow.com/users/302243/austin-phillips) for the tip (check out comments in his answer)

Comment: I think you should still have `.order_by('-datetime', '-id')`, just to show others that you wanted date ordered objects.

Comment: PS. While it's perfectly ok to provide your own answer and accept it, if there are already answers which have solved your problem it's better to accept one of the existing answers.

Answer (score 2):

With more of the actual code now revealed I'll provide the following hypothesis as to why this test is failing.

The `NodeActivation` model is incorrect.  The `datetime` field should be:

```
datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Using `datetime.datetime.now()` in a model definition will only be evaluated once.

Every time the setter creates a new `NodeActivation` record, the record will be created with the same date/time.  ie The date/time that the `NodeActivation` model was first evaluated.

Your getter only ever returns a single result.  But since both activation records have the same date/time, the ordering may be dependent on the database back end.  There will be two `NodeActivation` records in your database at the end of the test, which one is returned is indeterminate.

Comment: The reason I'm using default=datetime.datetime.now (NOTE: I'm passing the function NOT the result of calling the function - django calls it when creating a new record) is because I was having a hard time getting timezones to match between the database and python.  Fixing this is a TODO, but its not the reason the tests are failing (I just checked to make sure :-) ).  Also I think if it was, it'd also fail with SQLite as the backing DB.

Comment: @Hamish Sorry, you're right.  I missed that `default` was a function.  Even so, if your tests are running fast and the `datetime` fields for the activation records end up with the same timestamp, how are you guaranteed of the order of results in the getter?  Try adding a `-id` to your `order_by` in the getter.  Better still, dump the entire contents of the NodeActivation table at each step to verify your assumptions.

Comment: Of course! Nice thinking @Austin, thanks.  Thats totally it, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (not sure if its the same) going from SQLite to PostgreSQL using a setup method like you have for your initial database objects.

Example::

```
def setUp(self):
   user = User.objects.create_user(username='john', password='abbeyRd', email='john@thebeatles.com')
   user.save()
```

I found that this would work fine on SQLite, but on PostgreSQL I was getting database connection failures (it would still build the database like you said, but couldn't run the tests without a connection error).

Turns out, the fix is to run  your setup method as follows:

```
@classmethod
def setUpTestData(cls):
    user = User.objects.create_user(username='john', password='abbeyRd', email='john@thebeatles.com')
    user.save()
```

I don't remember the exact reason why this works and the other one didn't, but it had something to do with the connection to the database trying to reconnect every test if you use `setUp(self)` and if you use `setUpTestData(cls)` it only connects when the class is instantiated, but I might not have the details perfect. All I really know is it works!

Hope that helps, not sure if it addresses your exact issue, but it took me a good few hours to figure out, so I hope it helps you and maybe others in the future!